# If $f:\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}_+$ is strictly concave and strictly increasing with (...), is it true that $f''((f')^{-1}(x))\cdot(f')^{-1}(x)>-x$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

Is this true? If $f:\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}_+$ is strictly concave and strictly increasing with $f(0)=0$, $\lim_{x\to0^+}f'(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0$, then $$f''((f')^{-1}(x))\cdot (f')^{-1}(x)>-x$$ for all $x>1$.

Here $\mathbb{R}_+$ is the set of nonnegative real numbers.

Here are some simplifications. Since $f'((f')^{-1}(x))=x$ differentiation with respect to $x$ gives $f''((f')^{-1}(x))\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(f')^{-1}(x)=1$. Consequently, $$f''((f')^{-1}(x))\cdot (f')^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{\frac{d}{dx}(f')^{-1}(x)}\cdot(f')^{-1}(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\log{(f')^{-1}(x)}.$$ The graph of $f$ is represented below.

[image: Graph of f]

Comment: I don't understand the question. You write If $f: \mathbb{R}_+ \rightarrow ...$, what is the conclusion you want?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Made an update. The conclusion I want is $f''((f')^{-1}(x))\cdot (f')^{-1}(x)>-x$.

Comment: Do you want the conclusion to hold for all $x\in \mathbb{R}_+$? Or just for $x$ sufficiently large?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Made an update. It is enough for me that the conclusion holds for $x>1$ but if it holds for all $x\in\mathbb{R}_+$ that is even better.

Comment: Where does the question come from?

Comment: @punctureddusk From me. I was studying a particular problem and wanted to bound a function to proceed. The problem boils down to the stated inequality. It is not from a textbook but inspired by problems in a textbook.

Comment: How do you know that $f'$ is invertible? What kind of condition do you impose?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Does it not follow from the fact that $f''(x)<0$ for all $x>0$? I.e., $f'$ is strictly monotone.

Comment: Ah, I missed the strictly part of the concavity assumption. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false. Put $g(x) = f'(x)$. Then the question becomes: when $g : \mathbb R^+ \to \mathbb R^+$ is smooth, integrable at $0$ and strictly decreasing with $\lim_{x \to 0^+} g(x) = +\infty$ and $\lim_{x \to +\infty} g(x) = 0$, is it true that
$$g'(x) \cdot x > - g(x)$$
whenever $g(x) > 1$?

Put $h(x) = \log g(x)$, then the question becomes: when $h : \mathbb R^+ \to \mathbb R$ is smooth, $e^{h(x)}$ integrable at $0$ and $h(x)$ strictly decreasing with $\lim_{x \to 0^+} h(x) = +\infty$ and $\lim_{x \to +\infty} h(x) = -\infty$, is it true that
$$h'(x) > -\frac1x$$
whenever $h(x) > 0$?

---

We can now draw the graph of a counterexample: take $h(x)$ to grow not too fast at the origin (like $-0.5\log x$); before it dives below $0$ let it decrease very very fast, then continue the graph by letting $h(x)$ decrease to $-\infty$ in any way you like.

Because $h(x)$ decreases very fast at some point $x_0$ with $h(x_0) > 0$, we will have
$$h'(x_0) < -\frac1{x_0} \,.$$
More explicitly, take a smooth decreasing $h$ that satisfies
$$
h(x) = \begin{cases} -0.5 \log x & x \leq 0.001 \\
-1000 (x-2) & 1.999 \leq x \leq 2.001 \\
-x & 3 \leq x
\end{cases}$$
and $x_0 = 1.999$. We have $h'(x_0) \approx -500$ and $-1/x_0 \approx -0.5$.

Finally, put $f(x) = \int_0^x e^{h(t)} dt$.